# Which PHP framework with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

All PHP frameworks I know, have a deep integration with other UI frameworks like jQuery UI. I want know if there is any framework with built-in integration with twitter bootstrap or any framework independent from any UI framework to let me choose whatever I want. is there any?

Comment: Which PHP framework *doesn't* allow you to use your own HTML templates and javascript/css files? I would consider that to be a major failure.

Comment: I've done it with Zend. You just need to define classes -- I'm sure somebody already has some pre-made ViewHelpers for Bootstrap available online. This is not a reason to choose one framework over another though...

Comment: You can use Twitter Bootstrap easily with any framework you like!

Comment: Frameworks like YII and Zend have jquery ui and many predefined styles for UI elements, so should I remove them from framework and register Twitter Bootstrap instead?

Comment: What PHP frameworks have a deep integration with jQuery UI? I'd be interested in the answer to that - since the main ones (Zend, Symfony 1/2, CodeIgniter, Cake, DooPHP) aren't... as far as I know, anyway!

Comment: It's not about integration, it's about separation. Your views are separated from the rest of your app anyways, so you can put all the CSS classes into your markup you wish to... that's all there is to it.

Comment: Zend Framework doesn't have any predefined classes, if you mean forms, well, that's easy, just write your own decorators.

Comment: Zend Framework is just a collection of classes. I presume you mean [ZendX jQuery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.introduction.html) - but afaik you don't have to use it.

Comment: ZendX and YII have deeply integration with jQuery UI, in widgets

Comment: It seams http://dev.ppi.io/ is using Bootstrap as front-end component

Comment: You certainly have to look at [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/)

Comment: From what I can tell, ZendX != Zend. ZendX is just some extensions - just use Zend on its own, which you can integrate with anything.

Comment: I know Zend != ZendX, but using Zend without ZendX? I am looking for something like ZendX which is powered by Twitter Bootstrap...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good php framework that would allow you to use Twitter's Bootstrap is Symfony2 http://symfony.com/. They have a client-side resource management system called Assetic which allows you to package up any libraries you wish. So while it does not provide integration with twitters client-side framework it does allow you to write your own. Check it out at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic. Hope that helps.

Comment: I played with symfony2, Its suitable to use twitter-bootstrap as it is not associated with any other UI libraries.