# How do I set up environment to use a bootstrap theme together with PHP backend?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

I'm on a Chromebook using Crouton, running Lubuntu 14.04 LXDE.

I have full access to PHPStorm and will use it as my IDE.

Basically, I wish to use the bootstrap admin 2 theme together with a PHP backend framework that's light and simple. What framework should I use?

What should I install to get my environment working and get a local server running?

I have only small experience with Django for web development, and it was all handled from that framework itself. I have zero clue how to get this up with a PHP framework :/

Note that I do not have root access(Chrome OS running) and cannot create a new user/Environment from it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, light and simple don't exist, everything
requires some sort of education, whether its with help or doing it yourself.
With that said, Chromebook is for internet use, it really can't run the applications your looking for on a local environment such as WAMP without some hacks most likely. I would recommend you purchase Shared Hosting or a VPS, something cheap like $20 or $30 bucks a month and start building on a LAMP stack.

Bootstrap and PHP are really separate entities that should be learned on their own, but if it helps check this out [Which PHP framework with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479077/which-php-framework-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: A chromebook with chromeos is for light use - yeah - but with crouton i've got a decent lubuntu lxde distro running perfectly, there are no issues with it apart from a few root privileges(but these can be solved) -- so essentially, take the question as if i were on a normal ubuntu distro :)